# What regex to use to replace some strings with line breaks between two substrings?

Tags: regex

What regex to use to replace text between two strings (but the text also has line breaks)? Basically, how could I replace all occurrences of this:

```
            "points": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "x": 15500,
                "y": 3900,
                "state": 1
              }
            ]
```

with this:

```
            "points": []
```

Comment: `\[[\s\S]*\]` to $1 https://imgur.com/a/pPu3dUZ

Comment: Why are you trying to modify a json using a regex?

Comment: Use a JSON parser.

Answer (score 1):

`/"points": \[([^\]]*)\]/gm` will capture the contents of `points` in group 1, but this will easily break unless all of your input is exactly like your example.  For instance anything with an array inside will complicate things:

```
"points": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "x": 15500,
    "y": 3900,
    "states": [1,2,3]
   }
 ]
```

Since this is JSON, I would strongly recommend using a JSON library to manipulate this data instead of trying to process it as plain text with regex.  JSON, much like XML and HTML, is not a regular language so regular expressions cannot be used successfully in a general sense to manipulate it (even though it may work for very specific cases like this).

JSON is the right tool for the job.  https://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925

Answer (score 0):

`\[[\s\S]*\]`

to `$1`

`[\s\S]` find space and none space char. some regex engines dont work with `.*` so you could use `[\s\S]` as workaround for `.`

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGFEp.jpg) [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UZcT0d/1)